# Google Drive API, Python, Django

Tags: python, django, google-api-client

I have some csv files that I want to generate everytime I run the script and upload them directly to google drive. When you have the files locally, it is easy to upload them. But, when I want to upload them directly, I can't do that. I got this error instead :

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _csv.writer
```

I am using `googleapiclient.MediaFileUpload` to upload the files, and the method Create_Service from Google.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseUpload
from .Google import Create_Service

@api_view(['GET'])
def uploadFile(request):
    current_date = datetime.today().strftime("%d-%m-%y")
    content_disposition = 'attachment; filename=' + \
        'solde_quotidien_' + str(current_date) + '.csv'
    response = HttpResponse()
    response['Content-Disposition'] = content_disposition
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Date', 'Compte', 'Nom du client',
                     'Solde', 'Hold Balance', 'Type client'])

    client = ['2022', '34995277', 'Mehfoud', '1000000', '500']
    writer.writerow(client)

    # Upload a file
    # Le nom sur le cloud
    file_metadata = {
        'name': 'test.csv',
        'parents': ['']
    }

    
    media_content = MediaFileUpload(writer, mimetype='text/csv')
    file = service.files().create(
        body=file_metadata,
        media_body=media_content
    ).execute()
    print(file)
    return response
```

Apparently, the problem is with MediaFileUpload.
What should I do in this situation?

Thanks in advence.

**EDIT**
it worked with this, but it is writing all the data in one column, How can I use delimiters here?

```
file_metadata = {
        'name': 'test.csv',
        'parents': ['1QXu_mk5lWbNQyk-EiBnRSIQYmXqNmAdm']
    }

titles = ['Date', 'Compte', 'Nom du client',
              'Solde', 'Hold Balance', 'Type client']

file = io.StringIO()
    # file = io.BytesIO()
for t in titles:
      file.write(t)

media_content = MediaIoBaseUpload(
        file, mimetype='text/csv')

file = service.files().create(
        body=file_metadata,
        media_body=media_content
    ).execute()
```

Comment: MediaFileUpload's first argument in its initialization is the path to the file, e.g. 'test.csv'. You are getting the error because you are passing in the csv writer object instead. You can refer to https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.MediaFileUpload-class.html

Comment: Thnx for your feedback. I don't have the file locally, this is why I have to pass the csv writer, or what do you think?

Comment: You can either write to disk and upload, or just use the MediaInMemoryUpload class instead, where you can pass bytes as the argument (not the writer still): https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.MediaInMemoryUpload-class.html

Comment: Thanks. That helps a lot. It works when I used io.StringIO() and MediaIoBaseUpload. yet, there is another problem, It writes all the data in one column. How can I use different columns?

Comment: probably a delimiter problem